# Python web crawler counting words in all pages in a domain

Tags: python

Here is a simple web crawler I wrote in Python 3 that counts the words in each page in a domain, displays word count per page, and sums them up.

Tested on a multitude of web pages, works correctly so far.

What do you think of my code?

```
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "https://independencerpgs.com/"
html = urlopen(base_url)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), features="html.parser");

urls=[]
for link in bsObj.find_all('a'):
    if link.get('href') not in urls:
        urls.append(link.get('href'))
    else:
        pass
print(urls)

words=0
for url in urls:
    if url not in ["NULL", "_blank", "None", None, "NoneType"]:
        if url[0] == "/":
            url=url[1:]
        if base_url in url:
            if base_url == url:
                pass
            if base_url != url and "https://"in url:
                url=url[len(base_url)-1:]
        if "http://" in url:
            specific_url=url
        elif "https://" in url:
            specific_url = url
        else:
            specific_url = base_url + url
        r = requests.get(specific_url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, features="html.parser")
        for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
            script.extract()
        text = soup.get_text()
        lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
        chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
        text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)
        text_list = text.split()
        print(f"{specific_url}: {len(text_list)} words")
        words += len(text_list)
    else:
        pass
print(f"Total: {words} words")
```

Comment: How resilient/correct of a program are you aiming for? The main difficulty I see is finding and validating all the URLs. Also, what do you mean by _domain_, exactly?

Comment: I might have chosen the wrong term; the idea is to scan a whole site, find all the htm/html pages on it, and count the words in each.

Comment: _the idea is to scan a whole site_ Your code appears to be parsing the links found on a single page, though. _all the htm/html pages on it_ Can you be more specific still? _count the words in each_ The issue of defining what a word is still stands.

Answer (score 1):

It's readable and gets the job done as a script, but there is some redundancy in your if cases. Here's a streamlined version:

```
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "https://independencerpgs.com/"
html = urlopen(base_url)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), features="html.parser");

# Sets handle duplicate items automatically
urls=set()
for link in bsObj.find_all('a'):
    urls.add(link.get('href'))
print(urls)

words=0
for url in urls:
    # Having the logic this way saves 4 spaces indent on all the logic
    if url in ["NULL", "_blank", "None", None, "NoneType", base_url]:
        continue

    # The == base_url case is handled in the above `if`
    if url[0] == "/":
        specific_url = base_url + url # requests.get does not care about the num of '/'
    else:
        specific_url = url

    r = requests.get(specific_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, features="html.parser")
    for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
        # Use clear rather than extract
        script.clear()
    # text is text you don't need to preprocess it just yet.
    text = soup.get_text()
    print(f"{specific_url}: {len(text)} words")
    words += len(text)


print(f"Total: {words} words")
```

Depending on what you intend to do with that code, you might want to put it into functions or even create a class around it too.

Comment: Thanks! Will probably include it in a function once I create a UI for it, where the user enters the URL rather than have it coded into the script itself.

Comment: Looking at the "words += len(text)" statement, this script counts characters, not words. You need "words += len(text.split())". The OP has this correctly.